# Python wand: composite image with transparency

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

I'm trying to composite two images with Wand. The plan is to put image B at the right hand side of A and make B 60% transparent. With IM this can be done like this:

```
composite -blend 60 -geometry +1000+0 b.jpg a.jpg new.jpg
```

But with Wand I can only see the following with the `composite()` method: `operator, left, top, width, height, image`.

Is it possible with Wand?

Answer (score 3):

For the side-by-side to complete the `-geometry +1000+0`, you can composite the images side by side over a new image. For this example, I'm using [Image.composite_channel](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.0/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.composite_channel) for everything.

```py
with Image(filename='rose:') as A:
    with Image(filename='rose:') as B:
        B.negate()
        with Image(width=A.width+B.width, height=A.height) as img:
            img.composite_channel('default_channels', A, 'over', 0, 0 )
            img.composite_channel('default_channels', B, 'blend', B.width, 0 )
```

[image: side-by-side]

Notice the composite operator doesn't do affect much in the above example.

To achieve the `-blend 60%`, you would create a new alpha channel of 60%, and "copy" that to the source opacity channel.

I'll create a helper function to illustrate this technique.

```py
def alpha_at_60(img):
    with Image(width=img.width,
               height=img.height,
               background=Color("gray60")) as alpha:
        img.composite_channel('default_channels', alpha, 'copy_opacity', 0, 0)

with Image(filename='rose:') as A:
    with Image(filename='rose:') as B:
        B.negate()
        with Image(width=A.width+B.width, height=A.height) as img:
            img.composite_channel('default_channels', A, 'over', 0, 0 )
            alpha_at_60(B) #  Drop opacity to 60%
            img.composite_channel('default_channels', B, 'blend', B.width, 0 )
```

[image: side-by-side with transparenct]

Comment: When running this code with Wand 0.6.2 and ImageMagick 7.0, I get a  `ValueError: tuple.index(x): x not in tuple` error on `img.composite_channel('default_channels', alpha, 'copy_opacity', 0, 0)` with a reference to `COMPOSITE_OPERATORS.index(operator)` in the error message.

Comment: `copy_opacity` was renamed to `copy_alpha` in ImageMagick-7. This answer is from 5 years ago before IM-7 was released.

Comment: @emcconville any idea why this results in a multipage tiff file for me?