# Is there a bug in the Wand composite function when overlaying an image with transparency?

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

I'm using ImageMagick 7.0.8-27 Q16 x64 2019-02-09, and Wand 0.5.1, on a Windows 7 computer.

I want to overlay a text image with transparent background on a backdrop image.

wand.drawing.Drawing.composite() creates the exact same greyscale image for every composite operator.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import collections.abc
from wand.image import Image, COMPOSITE_OPERATORS
from wand.drawing import Drawing

wand_imageBackdrop = Image(filename='c:\\temp\\backdrop.png')
wand_imageOverlay = Image(filename='c:\\temp\\overlay.png')

for strCompositeOperator in COMPOSITE_OPERATORS:
  wand_imageBackdropClone = wand_imageBackdrop.clone()
  wand_imageOverlayClone = wand_imageOverlay.clone()

  with Drawing() as draw:
    draw.composite(operator=strCompositeOperator, left=0, top=0,
                   width=1080, height=1050, image=wand_imageOverlayClone)
    draw(wand_imageBackdropClone)

    wand_imageBackdropClone.save(filename='C:\\Temp\\composite_test_' + \
                                 strCompositeOperator + '.png')

  wand_imageBackdropClone.close()
  wand_imageOverlayClone.close()

wand_imageBackdrop.close()
wand_imageOverlay.close()
```

The below is the backdrop image.
[image]

The below is the overlay image.
[image]

Every composite operator creates the following, exact same greyscale image.
[image]

Can someone shed a light on this?  Is there any way to fix this?

The following StackOverflow posts shed some light on this issue.

[Python wand: composite image with transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377602/python-wand-composite-image-with-transparency)

[image composite result incorrect using python wand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865438/image-composite-result-incorrect-using-python-wand)

Is using [Image.composite_channel](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.0/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.composite_channel) the only way to correctly overlay an image with transparency over a background image?

Comment: Try changing the type of the backdrop image to `truecolor` (http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/wand/image.html#wand.image.IMAGE_TYPES)

Comment: Using truecolor or truecoloralpha (e.g. wand_imageBackdrop.type = 'truecolor') preserves the text colors, but it generates the exact same output image for every composite operator, as if the 'over' operator is used every time.  It solves my problem, but it's not a general solution for overlaying an image with transparency, for every composite operator in Wand.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by `creates the exact same greyscale image for every composite operator.` Are you saying that no matter what input image you get, that the resulting composite does not show that image, but shows the one above? Or are you saying that it just shows up as grayscale rather than color? Please clarify.

Comment: ImageMagick will make the output the same type as the first image in the sequence. You have to override that behavior by specifying type=truecoloralpha or truecolormatte depending upon which version of ImageMagick before you write the output. Sorry, I do not know Wand that well. Or you could change the order of the image and use another compose method such as dst_over. Apart from resizing one image, since they are not the same size, try the equivalent of `convert over.png back.png -compose dst_over -composite result.png`

Comment: @fmw42 I mean that when I run the code above, I get the exact same output image that I posted above, for every composite operator.  There is no change in output whatsoever when different composite operators are used.

Comment: @fmw42 Yes, using truecolor as the image type preserves the overlay image color.  However, that still doesn't solve the problem of every output being the same for every composite operator, as I reported in the earlier comment.

Comment: Have you tried just using composite_channel rather than draw.composite? See http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.1/wand/image.html

Comment: @fmw42 No, I have not tried composite_channel.  I was going to, but setting the type of the backdrop image to truecolor produced the result I wanted.  Right now, I only have the need to overlay an image with transparency onto another image, using the 'over' composite operator.  If some other need arises, such as using other composite operators, I would try out composite_channel to see how it works.

Comment: Well you are saying that draw.composite does not work and gives all the same results no matter what composite operator is used. So I though perhaps composite_channel might work properly. For PNG, to get a truecoloralpha image in command line, you need to preface the output file name with PNG32:, such as PNG32:outfile.suffix. I do not know if wand supports that.

Comment: @fmw42 That's my suspicion as well.  When the overlay image contains transparency, draw.composite performs the 'over' composite operation for every composite operation, except 'alpha'.  Other posts (linked in my question post above) have indicated that composite_channel works unlike draw.composite.  Wand supports truecoloralpha (e.g. wand_imageBackground.type = 'truecoloralpha' enables the alpha channel).

Comment: Looking at the draw.composite command in Wand 5.1, it shows 5 arguments before image. But the list of arguments shows 6, includes type – COMPOSITE_OPERATORS in addition to operator. So I am confused what should be specified there. Do you have to repeat the COMPOSITE_OPERATORS or specify type=COMPOSITE_OPERATORS?

Comment: @fmw42 Maybe the manual entry is incorrect at http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.1/wand/drawing.html.  I have not used the type parameter in my code above.  Maybe the type argument is for specifying the image type of the overlay image?  http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/wand/image.html#wand.image.IMAGE_TYPES

Comment: Looks like `CompositeImage` was removed from `DrawPrimitive()` in ImageMagick-7. @fmw42 can you confirm this? In ImageMagick-6, drawing performs a `DrawAffineImage` or a `CompositeImage` ([source](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick6/blob/master/magick/draw.c#L5375)), but in ImageMagick-7 just `DrawAffineImage` ([source](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/MagickCore/draw.c#L5453))

Comment: Sorry, I do not know the APIs for ImageMagick. I do not see anything about that in https://imagemagick.org/script/porting.php#cli. This still works in command line. `magick logo: -draw "image over 0,0 0,0 'rose:'" x.png` to draw one image over another.